# How to prevent SQL second order injections in java (Spring Application)

Tags: java, spring, security, constants, sql-injection

I have been facing the second order SQL injection in this following code

```
if(subjectId!=null){Query query= sessionFactory
            .getCurrentSession()
            .createSQLQuery(HubQueryConstants.GET_QUERY)
            .setParameter(MyConstants.SUBJECT_ID, subjectId)
            .setFirstResult(offset)
            .setMaxResults(limit)
            .setResultTransformer(
                    Transformers.aliasToBean(MyClass.class));}
```

My Constant file is :

Constant file is Final class

```
GET_QUERY="Select * from MyClass where id=:id ";
```

though it is in static query by default still my security report is giving it as Second order SQL injection

Should we declare constants in interface? to avoid Security issue?

Comment: I'd say your security report is wrong.

Comment: I think the concern is that you could inject sql in the id parameter of your query. But as your are using hibernate (i guess) your query is translated to  a preparedStement. So you should be save.

Comment: I am using Sql query in the above snippet  , though i am using HQL query my report is showing me second order SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

A SQL injection occurs, when a placeholder is replaced with a SQL term that alters the original SQL string so that the SQL does something different than intened.

You can find more details at [SQL_injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

SQL injection happens when the placeholder of the parameters are replaced. So declaring constants instead of reading the SQL from a properties file does not help. The injection happens later, independently from where the SQL string was obtained.

The easiest way to prevent SQL injection is by using prepared statements.

When a prepared statement is executed, the SQL string and the parameters are handled completely seperate by the SQL server, making SQL injection impossible.

With JPA you can use the annotation `javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;` to declare a SQL query that will be executed as prepared statement.

You find a tutorial using NamedNativeQuers at the end of [jpa-native-queries](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-native-queries/)